# Why is standard error of clustered observations not under-estimated?

Tags: r, standard-error, bias, clustered-standard-errors

I regularly read that clustering will cause standard errors to under-estimated. So I simulated two distributions - one with clustered observations, one without. In both cases the standard error is 0.09. Should standard error of clustered distribution not be smaller?

## Clustered - se = 0.09

[image]

```
rep(1:10, 100) -> dependent

set.seed(1)
dependent + rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 0.1) -> dependent

round(sqrt(var(dependent)/length(dependent)), 2)
```

## Not clustered - se = 0.09

[image]

```
set.seed(2)
rnorm(1000, mean = 5.49, sd = 2.87) -> independent

round(sqrt(var(independent)/length(independent)), 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You've drawn from two different populations, so your comparison is not valid. The question you want to ask is: *Given a clustered population*, what is the impact of ignoring clustering?

Let's say we have a clustered population. This is your `dependent` in the question, which I have renamed `popn` in the code below.

If we take a simple random sample of size $n = 100$ from `popn`, we get a standard deviation estimate of 3.00 (the true value of the SD is 2.87).

Now we'll take a cluster sample. We'll select two clusters each of size $n = 50$. The SD of the cluster sample is 1.51, which is an under-estimate of the true SD. An underestimate of the SD gives an under-estimate of the SE.

```
rep(1:10, 100) -> popn
set.seed(1)
popn + rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 0.1) -> popn
sd(popn) # true population SD

hist(popn, breaks = 100)

randsamp <- sample(x = popn, size = 100, replace = FALSE)
sd(randsamp) # SRS SD

clus_to_sample <- sample(x = 1:10, size = 2, replace = FALSE)
clussamp <- c()
for (i in clus_to_sample) {
  clussamp <- append(x = clussamp
                     , values = sample(
                       popn[ rep(1:10, 100) == i ]
                       , size = 50
                       , replace = FALSE
                       ))
}
sd(clussamp) # cluster sample SD
```